# SharePoint admin configuration inaccessible

Tags: windows, sql-server, database-administration, sharepoint-services

I successfully moved three out of four SharePoint Service databases from one database server to another, except for the admin content database.  Now I am unable to access the Admin Configuration on the old or new server, but the main SharePoint site and search function normally.  I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting the farm

Configuration: 1 IIS server on Win2003, 1 old database server, 1 new database server (both SQL'05)

Any ways for me to re-access the Admin site, in the new correct configuration?  I'll even do a some configuration in the database if necessary.

thank you!

Comment: How did you do the move?  What commands, etc.

Comment: Have you seen this article? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723.aspx

Comment: Yes I have referred to that article for the initial moves; although it did not work for the one database in question

Comment: Is there a possibility of creating a new admin site, using the existing content databases from the main sharepoint site?

Comment: SharePoint Admin site simply wouldn't load up after I moved the databases and relinked them.  Is it possible to blow away the admin site, and keep the existing content databases?, or is it possible to "hack the Config database (which by all means appeared to transfer okay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I tested and decided to create a new admin site, and attach the existing store by adding a new content database, and giving it the name of the existing database.  I had to reindex the search, which took a while though